# Is it possible to handle iOS native app permissions in appium using java

Tags: java, appium-ios, xcuitest

I have referred appium documentation for desired capabilities.

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

For android autoGrantPermissions capability is there but for iOS apps no capability is found to handle app permissions.

if there any workaround or any methods to handle native app permissions for iOS, Please suggest.

Note: In appium inspector, its displaying as " interactions are not available for this element"

Comment: Kindly provide snapshot and code-snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below snippet has worked for me

https://discuss.appium.io/t/xcuitestdriver-autoacceptalerts/13761/11

```
try {
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}
catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
logger.warn("Alert is not present" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle permissions can be by accepting of dismissing the incoming alert (I'm using ruby):

```
def alert_accept
  $driver.execute_script("mobile: alert", {
    'action': "accept"
  });
end

def alert_dismiss
  $driver.execute_script("mobile: alert", {
    'action': "dismiss"
  });
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via capabilities.
try autoAcceptAlerts.

```
IOSMobileCapabilityType.AUTO_ACCEPT_ALERTS
```